# Hadoop shuffle uses which protocol?

Tags: hadoop, protocols, mapreduce, distributed-computing

During the shuffle stage of Hadoop data the mapped data is transferred across nodes of the clusters
according to the partitions for the reducer.
What protocol does Hadoop use for performing the shuffle of data across nodes for the reduce stage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I really laughed for the first time, but the whole shuffeling and merging is done by a `HTTPServlet`.

You can see this in the `Tasktrackers` sourcecode in the anonymous class `MapOutputServlet` It gets a HTTP request with IDs of the tasks and jobs and then it is going to transfer the incoming input stream into the local filesystem on disk.

Comment: Is HTTP inefficient? What are the alternatives?

Comment: Yes, RPC would be an alternative. A co-worker threw in that the network stack is optimized for HTTP usage (really?), so this may be faster. But I think you should ask this on the mailing-list why they choose HTTP over anything else.