# How does Reducers collect map ouput in Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

Do Reducers pull map output or do Maps push there output to reducers? If Reducers pull then how do they know which Maps (slave machines) to contact. Does the JobTracker tell Reducers which machine to contact?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8285217/hadoop-shuffle-uses-which-protocol Actually it isn't named like your title, but also the same question.

Answer (score 0):

This happens completely under the hood. Essentially the MapReduce Framework initiates a shuffle and sort which happens over the network and pass it to the reducers. Your Reducer or Mapper dont do any push or pull, its the Map reduce framework does it and also if you have your custom partitioner, comparator or group comparator it does the shuffling and sorting of data according to those before pushing it to the reducers.

I hope it helps.